# matplotlib for stock data analysis plot not correct

Tags: python, matplotlib, stock

I'm using matplotlib to draw trendance line for stock data.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
A = pd.read_csv('daily/A.csv', index_col=[0])
print(A)
AAL = pd.read_csv('daily/AAL.csv', index_col=[0])
print(AAL)
A['Close'].plot()
AAL['Close'].plot()
plt.show()
```

then result is:

```
             High    Low   Open  Close      Volume  Adj Close
Date                                                         
1999-11-18  35.77  28.61  32.55  31.47  62546300.0      27.01
1999-11-19  30.76  28.48  30.71  28.88  15234100.0      24.79
1999-11-22  31.47  28.66  29.55  31.47   6577800.0      27.01
1999-11-23  31.21  28.61  30.40  28.61   5975600.0      24.56
1999-11-24  30.00  28.61  28.70  29.37   4843200.0      25.21
...           ...    ...    ...    ...         ...        ...
2020-06-24  89.08  86.32  89.08  86.56   1806600.0      86.38
2020-06-25  87.35  84.80  86.43  87.26   1350100.0      87.08
2020-06-26  87.56  85.52  87.23  85.90   2225800.0      85.72
2020-06-29  87.36  86.11  86.56  87.29   1302500.0      87.29
2020-06-30  88.88  87.24  87.33  88.37   1428931.0      88.37

[5186 rows x 6 columns]
         High    Low   Open  Close       Volume  Adj Close
Date                                                          
2005-09-27  21.40  19.10  21.05  19.30     961200.0      18.19
2005-09-28  20.53  19.20  19.30  20.50    5747900.0      19.33
2005-09-29  20.58  20.10  20.40  20.21    1078200.0      19.05
2005-09-30  21.05  20.18  20.26  21.01    3123300.0      19.81
2005-10-03  21.75  20.90  20.90  21.50    1057900.0      20.27
...           ...    ...    ...    ...          ...        ...
2020-06-24  13.90  12.83  13.59  13.04  140975500.0      13.04
2020-06-25  13.24  12.18  12.53  13.17  117383400.0      13.17
2020-06-26  13.29  12.13  13.20  12.38  108813000.0      12.38
2020-06-29  13.51  12.02  12.57  13.32  114650300.0      13.32
2020-06-30  13.48  12.88  13.10  13.07   68669742.0      13.07

[3715 rows x 6 columns]
```

yes, the begin of 2 stocks is different, the end date is same.
so i get the plot is like this:
[stockplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjEDU.png)

this is not normal like others.
so, who could give me any advice, to draw a normal trendance line for 2 stocks?

Answer (score 0):

You can try for making two different plots with same limits and then put one over the another for comparison.